# Handling database operations with .net core mvc get request

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I have a controller like the image below. This controller hides the relevant record in the database when the fetch request is sent. Do I need to use http post for such operations in this project that I wrote with Entity framework core? The problem with this controller is that the admin executes the javascript code fetch(`https://localhost:5001/admin/deletepost?delete=url`) on any page. As soon as this get query runs, the relevant record is hidden or deleted from the database. Is it safe as it is? How can I make it more secure? Thank you very much to everyone who replied.
[image]
[image]

Although this method is only accessible to the admin, will the deletion of the record as a result of the admin sending this request cause a deficit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For several reasons, POST is more secure than GET.

GET parameters are passed through the URL. This means that the parameters are stored in the server log and browser history. When using GET, you can also easily change the data submitted to the server because it is in the address bar.

The problem when comparing the security between the two is that POST may block temporary users, but it cannot block malicious users. It is very easy to forge a POST request and should not be fully trusted.

The biggest security problem of GET is not the end user's maliciousness, but the third party sending a link to the end user.

Another point is that you must consider where to use GET and POST, because GET should only be used for operations that do not change database information, and only request or read information and POST data should be used when the data will be changed.

Some web scanners will automatically click on each link (usually a GET request) instead of in a button or form (usually a POSTS request) to avoid changing the database, but for example, if you perform a delete operation after the link, you The risk of clicking on the link may be easier with more automated tools.